# How to find an image from an array of images and put it in a modal window using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do article preview function that shows title, text, tags and an image in a modal window using Jquery. I have manage to do the title and text so far.

The problem is the image and the tags. I have currently three images that I can choose from, but that could change in the future.

The paths to the images shows up in the source code so there is no problem there.

The problem is the Jquery stuff. I guess I have to do an $.each function or something, but so far I only get all the image paths or it shows Object object in the modal window.

Can someone help me with this?

Here is a part of the form.

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
 @foreach($images as $image)
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="{{$image->id}}" />
  <label for="image_name" class="form-check-label">{{$image->name}}</label>
  <img class="my-card-img" src="{{asset('storage'.$image->path)}}"/>
 @endforeach
</div>
<button  id="preview" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
    Preview
</button>
```

Here is the Jquery so far, but $.each function logs all the image paths.

```
$('#preview').click(function () {
  var previewModal = $('#previewModal');
  var title = $('input[name=title]').val();
  var body = $('textarea[name=body]').val();

  //This will log all the image paths.
  $(".my-card-img").each(function(){ 
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    console.log(imgSrc);
   });

  previewModal.find('#title').text(title);
  previewModal.find('#body').text(body);
  previewModal.modal('show');
 });
```

Source code looks like this.

```
   <div class="form-group form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="1" />
  <label for="image_name" class="form-check-label">First image</label>
  <img class="my-card-img" src="path is ok"/>
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="2" />
  <label for="image_name" class="form-check-label">Image two</label>
  <img class="my-card-img" src="path is ok"/>
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="3" />
  <label for="image_name" class="form-check-label">Image three</label>
  <img class="my-card-img" src="path is ok"/>
      </div>
```

Comment: What framework/library are you using? `@foreach($images as $image)` doesn't look like regular html to me

Comment: You only have one button and numerous images. Not clear how you expect this to work in the first place. My guess is you would want a button for each one but that is not what is shown

Comment: I'm using Laravel. I have three radiobuttons on the page and depending on witch I click I want that image that corrsponds to that radiobutton to show up in the modal window. I hope you understand. My native language is not english.

Comment: When I click the preview button I want the image that corrsponds to the radiobutton to show up in the modal window.

Comment: Your problem is that button itself is out of the parent div of image so you have multiple images inside the div and one button outside the div .formgroup, include button in the foreach loop and then use parent().find() to get the image crossponding to that button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created sample html that will equal to your scenario. I have included three div's with the class **child-image** you can generate your images inside laravel @foreach loop and.I wrapped all images inside div that has class **"image-container"**

in your case as an example

```
 @foreach($images as $image)
<div class="child-image">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="{{$image->id}}" />
        <label class="form-check-label">{{$image->name}}</label>
        <img style="width: 50px;" class="my-card-img" src="{{asset('storage'.$image->path)}}" />
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**IN Your HTML**

```
<div id="image-container">
    <div class="child-image">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="1" />
        <label class="form-check-label">Sri Lanka</label>
        <img style="width: 50px;" class="my-card-img" src="https://restcountries.eu/data/lka.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-image">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="2" />
        <label class="form-check-label">India</label>
        <img style="width: 50px;" class="my-card-img" src="https://restcountries.eu/data/ind.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-image">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="images" value="3" />
        <label class="form-check-label">Ireland</label>
        <img style="width: 50px;" class="my-card-img" src="https://restcountries.eu/data/irl.svg" />
    </div>

    <button id="preview" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Preview
    </button>
</div>
```

**For Modal just i used bootstrap**

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="previewModal">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img style="width: 50px;" class="my-card-img" src="" />
            <p id="image_name"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**and to get image and name from the clicked radio button use jQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preview').click(function() {
        var selectedImage = $("input[type='radio']:checked"); // gets the selected checkbox from all radios
        var image_childWrapper = selectedImage.parent(); // selects the parent of the selected radio button
        var imageSrc = image_childWrapper.find("img").attr("src"); // find the correspondence image to that selected radio button 
        var imageName = image_childWrapper.find("label").html(); // gets the image name

        var previewModal = $('#previewModal');
        $("#image_name").html(imageName); // sets the image nam on modal paragraph tag
        previewModal.find('.modal-body').find("img").attr("src", imageSrc); // sets the modal window image source  for display
        previewModal.modal('show'); // show the modal
    });
});
```

to select image name and image source i have html tags here.